# Using VBA to insert a row above specific values in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table organized similarly to as follows:

```
   Open Date    MaturityDate    ZeroRate
    5-May-15    5-May-15    0.006999933
    5-May-15    6-May-15    0.0069999329
    5-May-15    5-Jun-15    1
    5-May-15    6-Jul-15    0.008993128
    5-May-15    5-Aug-15    0.006744264
    5-May-15    5-Nov-15    0.006912941
    5-May-15    5-May-16    0.007104633
    5-May-15    5-May-17    0.006910929
    5-May-15    6-Nov-17    0.007017292
    5-May-15    7-May-18    0.00712202
    5-May-15    5-Nov-18    1
    5-May-15    6-May-19    0.008551509
    5-May-15    5-Nov-19    0.009734602
    5-May-15    5-May-20    0.010916848
    5-May-15    5-Nov-20    0.011779622
    5-May-15    5-May-21    0.012632521
    5-May-15    5-Nov-21    1
    5-May-15    5-May-22    0.014366506
    5-May-15    7-Nov-22    0.014935518
    5-May-15    5-May-23    0.0154865
```

I'm trying to code a VBA script to insert a row into the sheet above every instance of the value of "1" in the third column. Here's what I've written so far:

```
Sub RowInserter()
Dim d As Integer
d = Range("C:C").End(xlDown).Row
Dim c As Range
  For i = d To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "1" Then
      Rows(Cells(i, 1).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have coded right, but only one mistake. You should type **3** instead of **1** in line:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value = "1" Then
```

Change that **3**, like:

```
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "1" Then
```

Comment: Hey thank you it's working perfectly now. 

Do you have any suggestions for this next problem? Say I want to sum the numbers between the blank rows. Is there a way to automate it so that it selects the range only between blank rows, for the entire table? (several thousand rows)

Comment: It is possible. Give it a try and let me know if you stuck with any issue.

Comment: I'm using a function I wrote in VBA to interpolate between values; the syntax is =Interpolate(reference cell, table range). 

I'm trying to automate it so that the "Table range" part is the range between the blank rows.

I'm trying to do something like 

cell D2: =IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(C2),INTERPOLATE(B2, INDEX(A:A,LOOKUP(2,1/ISBLANK(C$2:C2),ROW(C$2:C2))):C2),""),"")

but this is horribly convoluted and doesn't seem to be working; what would be a better approach?

Comment: You want to use formula or VBA?

Comment: either is fine; I tried using a formula since I couldn't think of a way to do it in VBA.